# Set background-image using jQuery css property

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am able to load image in div but I want load as background image using jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
src = 'image.jpg';

$(".imagePreview").html(src ? "<img src='" + ImagePath + src + "'>" : "");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hope this will help you

```
$('.imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Comment: The OP tried something like ternary operator this should be also not a right answer